# HTML - How to display "N/A" on null values

Tags: html, foreach, model

This code below will not show N/A on null values. I know I need to do something different on the foreach.

```
  <td>
                    @foreach (var item in items) 
                    {                                                
                        @(item.Location.Warehouse?.Name ?? "N/A")                       
                    }
</td>
```

This code below does work but not using foreach.

```
<td>
                    @(item.Plant?.Name ?? "N/A")
</td>
```

Just need to know how to use the foreach for null values. I tried using if-else statement but that didn't work.

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @DCR I'm using C#

Answer (score 0):

The thing that immediately jumps out to me for the first section of code is that you are using `foreach (var item in items)` and then referencing items, not the single item

Comment: Sorry about that. That was just typo. Fixed now.

Comment: @m.woods What about  trying @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Location.Warehouse?.Name) ? "N/A" : "") otherwise I see a lot of people insisting on using a for loop instead. But I think this should work if it is a string. Otherwise could do @(item.Location.Warehouse ?? "N/A")